# Animated add / remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to use fadeIn / Out when adding and removing of #left element in this code. Can you remove a class and animate that same element?

```
 var window_width = $(window).width();
 var scroll_amount = window_width * .75;
 var left=$('#latest_wrapper');

 $('#latest_wrapper #right').click(function() {
    $('#left').removeClass('none');
    $('#latest_wrapper').scrollTo('+=' + scroll_amount, 300);   
 });    

 $('#latest_wrapper #left').click(function() {
    $('#latest_wrapper').scrollTo('-=' + scroll_amount, 300);

    actual_left = left.scrollLeft() - scroll_amount;
    if(actual_left <= 0){
        $("#left").addClass('none');
    }
 });


 # HTML page
 <div id="latest_wrapper" data-offset="1">

    <div id="left" class="arrow_wrapper none">
        <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="arrow_wrapper">
        <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
    </div>

    ... more
```

Comment: Why at the "SAME" time?  Or are you thinking of something like: `$item.removeClass("hai").animate(opts);` or were you talking about toggling between classes as a part of the animation?

Comment: So you want to fadeOut an element in when a class is added, and fade it out when removing a class? Please clarify.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? There is no reason you couldn't fadeIn/Out an element and remove/add a class from/to that same element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove a class and animate that same element?
for that part of your question I can say:

```
   $("#left").addClass('none').fadeOut();
```

but if you face some css that will make class none to be display none, then you must do animation first and then add your class.

```
   $("#left").fadeOut('normal', function(){
        $(this).addClass('none');
   });
```

you can do the same with fadeIn()

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I'm assuming that you want to animate based on the properties being set in the CSS.

There are a bunch of options here, depending on your specific use-case.

The easiest and cleanest way would be to use CSS transitions along with your existing JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/j85Az/

```
.arrow_wrapper {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

---

If you want to use JavaScript for this, you could use jQuery UI:

http://api.jqueryui.com/addclass/

---

If you don't want to use jQuery UI, you will most-likely need to do this manually using jQuery animate:

```
$('#left').animate({
  //-- new CSS here
}, {
  complete: function () {
    $(this).removeClass('none');
  }
});
```